# Float right header with fixed width and no wrap

Tags: html, css, css-float, overflow

Let's say I have two blocks, one fixed-width block, one dynamic-width block.  I want to put these two blocks on the same line with no wrapping.  If the window shrinks, the dynamic width block will shrink (probably with a min width), then after a certain point it will just hide text (overflow hidden).

If the fixed width block is on the left this is easy

```
<div style="width: 800px; border: 1px solid black; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden;">
  <div style="display: inline-block; width: 150px;">Fixed width block</div>
  <div style="display: inline-block;">Loooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong liiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiine</div>
</div>
```

But I can't figure out how to achieve this if I want the fixed width block to be on the right hand side, without using table layout.

I've tried many variants of `float: right` with `overflow`, `white-space` and so on, but no luck.  I've tried searching through Stack but none of the solutions provided seem to fit my use case.  Most solutions I find require making both blocks have a fixed width, which is not what I want.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use this CSS

```
<div style="width: 800px; border: 1px solid black; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden;">
    <div style="white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis !important; display: inline-block; width: 150px;>Fixed width block</div>
    <div style="white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis !important; display: inline-block;">Looooong liiiiiiine</div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's not what I'm asking though.  I want the fixed width block to the on the right hand side.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
<div style="width: 800px; border:1px solid black;">
    <div style="width: 150px; float: right;">
        Fixed width block
    </div>
    <div style="width: auto; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden;">
        Loooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong liiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiine
    </div>
</div>
```